# The camera captures images in ionic 4 Project. How to added geolocation (latitude and longitude) that image save in phone gallery with location

Tags: angular7, ionic4

The camera captures images in ionic4(angular6) Project. How to added geolocation (latitude and longitude)that image and save in phone gallery with location

Answer (score 0):

Piexifjs might help you. Here is an example:

`https://piexifjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample.html#insert-exif-into-jpeg`